# Controller does not work anymore after Laravel 8 update

Tags: json, controller, laravel-8

```
public function show($article){
    return $article;
}
```

This will return a row in JSON format. Now, this does not return anything, just the brackets []. Also, my update method stopped working:

```php
public function update(Request $request,Article $article){
    $article->update($request->all());

    return response()->json($article,200);
}
```

My get all works perfectly which something goes like:

```
public function index(){
    return Article::all();
}
```

These are all working, but when I updated to Laravel 8, it stopped working. I already had to work around it, but I like the format above because it is short and simple.

Comment: What are your corresponding routes?

Comment: Hi,
Here are the routes:
   Route::get('articles/{articles}',[ArticleController::class,'show']);
   Route::put('articleUpdate',[ArticleController::class,'update']);
   Route::get('articles',[ArticleController::class,'index']);
Thanks.